# Enter as tab directive does not work on input field generated by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

As the title, I'm using ionic and angularjs to learn develop a web app and I encounter some problem. I create a directive and try to make keyboard act as "Tab" when pressing "Enter" for input fields. It works perfectly fine with static  tags in html. But, when I'm using ng-repeat to generate input fields, it does not work.

Here is my html:

```
<form enter-as-tab ng-controller="ListCtrl">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item class="item item-dark" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <input class="item-note" type="{{item.type}}">
        {{item.name}}
        </input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</form>
```

Here is my controller and directive:

```
.controller('ListCtrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
}])

.directive('enterAsTab', function () {
    return {
    "restrict" : "A",
    "link" : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $('input').on("focus keypress", function(e) {
            var inputs = $(this).closest('form').find(':input:visible,select:visible');
            var nextInput = inputs.eq( inputs.index(this) + 1 );
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                nextInput.focus();
                if(nextInput.attr('type')!=="submit")
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
            return true;
        });
    }}
})
```

Hope you guys can help me, thanks very much!

Comment: Need to use event delegation. The elements need to exist which they don't when your code is run. ...try `element.on("focus keypress",'input'...`

Comment: element.bind('keydown', function (e, inputs) { ..... + var code = e.keyCode || e.which; if (code === 13){}

Comment: I tryed element.on("focus keypress","input"...), the console shows Error: [jqLite:onargs] jqLite#on() does not support the `selector` or `eventData` parameters

Comment: if I use element.bind('keydown', function (e, inputs) , how could I find the next input field to focus on with angularjs? my previous method is simple to find next input field since actually use jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charlietfl your answer is perfect, I find the reason why it appears that error.I need to declare jquery.js before angularjs

Comment: I apply this method, it can work on chrome, but not work on ios simulator, the keyboard is hidden when I click 'go'